# SSRS dynamic rows

Tags: sql, reporting-services, asp-classic, report

I am new to SSRS and I am facing an issue in SSRS 2008. I am hiding and showing a table depending upon the condition, but after hiding its shows empty space/row.

Comment: Add more details in order to help you. It is imposible to know what is causing your issue without see your tablix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the table is reserved and you can't get rid of it. What you can do is display some message like 'no data' etc when you want to hide it. You can display the message in a text box in the table, the text expression will be based on the condition.

Comment: Hi, but my client is not accepting it. he needs the white space to get off..!!

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that when your table is invisible, you're still seeing white space that the table would've occupied if it were visible?  Have you tried setting the following in the Report properties?

```
ConsumeContainerWhitespace = True
```

Comment: Yes, the report was developed in 2005 and its .rdlc file.i could found the setting

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the ColumnVisibility/RowVisibility property to false in addition to ConsumeContainerWhitespace = True? This should remove the vertical white space